# Where is the documentation for clipit hiding?

Tags: gtk, clipboard-manager

`man clipit` for Ubuntu says nothing about useful stuff like <kbd>ctl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> for find in history, <kbd>ctl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>ctl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>. There are no help widgets, and my system displays no task bar icon.  Where is the documentation? `clipit -h` reads much like the man page.

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions together. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Clipit seems to have not a really large amount of support.

Some assistance can be found on their github page https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt, particularily the document https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt/blob/master/README.md which lists the default keybindings for clipit.

The few default keybindings are:

- History   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
- Actions   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
- Menu  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
- Search    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
- Offline mode  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

Speaking of the github, this would be the appropriate place to initiate a feature request for clipit, or volunteer effort to improve the manpage.